# Checking with JS/VB user is authenticated in windows domain

Tags: javascript, windows, active-directory, ldap

I'm developing intranet site for user in one windows domain. Authentication is integrated with LDAP/Active Directory.

If it possible to check user authentication status in windows (is authenticated and is right domain) to autologin him?

I expect solution that works only in IE (some specific JS/VB object or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use IIS, have the server request Windows authentication (SPNEGO) and you are done. You do not need to perform any LDAP bind.